# Deploying qt applications on symbian along with frameworks

Tags: qt, deployment, symbian, s60

I've developed an app from symbian. I need to create a sis symbian installer file along with qt framework in the same sis file. Right now i installed the framework separately which is like 12MB and the QTMobility which is around 2MB.

How to create a installer that has the required QT frameworks api and reduce the installer size. And the installer which can work offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to embed the sis files of Qt and QtMobility in the sis file of the application.

Study the relevant part of the documentation of the [Software Installation Toolkit](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Installing/index.html):

[Embedding SIS files within other SIS files](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Installing-ref/PKG_format/PKG_body/PKG_lines_embedded-sis.html):

> A SIS file may contain a number of embedded or nested SIS files. [...]
>   Embedding SIS files might be useful for packaging multiple components
>   into a single SIS file, but which can later be removed independently
>   of each other. For example, if a SIS file needs to install an
>   application and a library that is shared with other installed
>   applications, the shared library could be installed as an embedded SIS
>   file, so that when the application is uninstalled, the shared library
>   will remain on the phone if still required by other applications.

[How to create an install file containing embedded install files](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/ToolsAndUtilities94/Installing/index.html):

A SIS file can include other SIS files. To do this, in the PKG file, include the name and location of the embedded install file(s), and their package UID(s), prefixed with the @ symbol.

```
IF NOT package(0x2001E61C)
; install Qt.sis only if not already installed
@"Qt.sis", (0x2001E61C)
endif

IF NOT package(0x2002AC89)
; install QtMobility.sis only if not already installed
@"QtMobility.sis", (0x2002AC89)
endif
```

Comment: thanks @Bill will work on that and let you know if it works for me..:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [smart installer](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Nokia_Smart_Installer_for_Symbian) for Symbian.

Comment: The installer should work offline, so no dice with smart installer